# Problem with the DataTable and DataGridView objects

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I have the following problem

In my aplication I doing some calculations and after it put them into DataTable object (6 columns, data in the latest one is most important). To view the results I put them into DataGridView object and there is my problem. Depending on the data contained in the last column I want to mark the cells on the appropriate colors. And I don't know if I should do this on the DataGridView object because this is user interfaces? Where I can do this? DataTable object doesn't have a style properties?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: What language you are referring to? C#? If it is C#/.Net, please add these tags as well. It will help you to get answers sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CellPainting event of the DataGridView to format your cells based on their content.

e.g. `

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {

            switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName)
            {
                case "Description":
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                case "NormalRoom":
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                case "Colour1":
                case "Colour2":
                    {
                        Color co = Color.White;
                        if (e.Value != null && e.Value != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            co = string2Color((string)e.Value);
                        }
                        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

etc.`

Comment: Karol's solution would work but may be slow if the dataset is large. Also you would need to ensure it ran each time the data changed. My method has the advantage that it is automatic and efficient as it only needs to handle the data actually visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've done simething like this:

```
 public void setABCColor(DataGridView DGV)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DGV.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((string)DGV.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value == "A")
            {
                DGV.Rows[i].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else if ((string)DGV.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value == "B")
            {
                DGV.Rows[i].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {
                DGV.Rows[i].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this acceptable? Is this not change the assumption of the MVC design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the logic in the Cell Formatting event of the datagridview.
These would also reflect changes in case your data changes dynamically based on some calculations in the grid
something like

```
void myDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Value.ToString() == "A" )
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```